# Ставится ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Тянитесь как можно сильнее

Answer (score 7):

Запятая не нужна. Условий для запятой нет. Нет ни сравнительного оборота, ни придаточного предложения.

Comment: И мягкий знак в заголовке не нужен.